# Does it matter how you connect the CSV files in Tableau Public?

Tags: visualization, tableau-desktop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63VWA.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7NHs.png)

All the tables have the same primary key which is "product_id". Wondering if it matters whether the lines are connected like the one in the picture or horizontally.

[2nd screenshot for comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odHh2.png)

I already created my SQL notebook but now I want to create a tableau dashboard and before I do that, I will need to connect the csv files. Looking for advice.

I noticed you can connect csv files in multiple ways but I dont know if that will affect the results/numbers of dashboard and metrics.

Comment: If the question has been answered, you could accept the answer in order to marke the thread as completed.

Answer (score 2):

The main difference between your two scenario is that in the first one you're using relationships (dynamic approach) while the second one is join oriented (static approach).

I'd highly recommend to have a look at [Tableau documentation](https://help.tableau.com/current/online/en-us/datasource_relationships_learnmorepage.htm)

Basically with relationships you'll bypass the "static connection" within tables and may allow you to get the same result with more flexibility.